# Accessing Data From Dynamically Generated TextFields

Tags: dynamic, javafx

I'm currently working on functionality that would allow the user to add a set of checkboxes, textfields, and buttons on demand. Afterward, I would like to be able to access the text stored in the textfield as well as the state of the checkbox.

My current code is as follows:

```
    @FXML VBox box = new VBox(10);
   {
        HBox horizBox = new HBox(10);
        Button button3 = new Button("Hi");
        TextField textTest = new TextField();
        CheckBox check3 = new CheckBox();
        box.getChildren().addAll(horizBox);
        horizBox.getChildren().addAll(textTest, check3, button3);
        System.out.println(textTest.getText());
    }
```

Even after giving a variety of inputs, the output is still blank. How do I access the data in a dynamically generated textbox? For example, if I wanted to get the input from the fourth textbox that the user made, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happens to the text field between `TextField textTest = new TextField();` and `System.out.println(textTest.getTest());`, so the output is going to be empty. When do you want to get the text from the text field, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Never write `@FXML Thing thing = new Thing();`.  The thing has already been created by an `FXMLLoader`, you don't need a new one, and if you do create a new one, things will likely not work as you expect.